# Typeclass namespace shadowing results in accidental recursion

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble defining an instance of `Show` for a custom datatype.

```
data Circle = Circle { x::Float, y::Float, r::Float }

instance Show Circle where 
show :: Circle -> String
show circle = concat $ 
  intersperse "," (map Prelude.show [x circle, y circle, r circle])
```

This all lives in a module called `Main.` Calling `Main.show circ` for some Circle `circ` results in a stack overflow exception. Why is even a qualified usage of `Prelude.show` being interpreted by GHC as a call to the function I'm defining right here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an indentation problem.  Here is the correction:

```
data Circle = Circle { x::Float, y::Float, r::Float }

instance Show Circle where 
  -- Illegal syntax
  -- show :: Circle -> String
  show circle = concat $ 
    intersperse "," (map show [x circle, y circle, r circle])
```

When you forget to indent, you are getting two *separate* declarations:

```
instance Show Circle where { }
```

And a function:

```
show :: Circle -> String
```

Let's ignore the function, because it never gets called.  When you define an empty class instance, you get the default definitions for the functions.  This will pass the Haskell type checker because `show` defaults to using `showsPrec`, and `showsPrec` defaults to using `show`.  If you override one or both of the two methods, you get a working instance of `Show`.  If you override neither, the default implementations become mutually recursive and overflow the stack.

### About `Prelude.show`

There is only one `show` in the above code, and that is `Prelude.show`.  When you implement a class, you are not implementing a *new* function named "show", but you are providing a new implementation for the generic function `Prelude.show`.

Comment: Excellent! Never again will I forget the indentation thing. Regarding Prelude.Show, is the correct way to think about it that the instance declaration is like adding a new case for pattern matching in the show function?

Comment: An instance is more like a record full of functions that suffice to implement the class when the types match the instance type. In GHC, the instance (in the form of a dictionary of functions) is sometimes passed as an extra implicit parameter to functions with a type class constraint. This is just an implementation strategy rather than part of the definition of type classes, but it might give some insight into how they work.

Comment: @Cardano: Both ways of thinking about it are good.  Your way of thinking about it (like an additional case for pattern matching) is the traditional way of thinking about polymorphic functions, and thinking about them that way will make it easier to read papers and literature on the subject.  What Levi Pearson mentions, the instance dictionary, is also useful, but it is kind of an implementation detail for Haskell, but knowing about the instance dictionary can help you sort out the "why" of "why doesn't this work in Haskell".

Answer (score 0):

We also can use `InstanceSigs` extension for use signatures inside instances.
Don't forget use spaces inside "`where`".

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}
data Circle = Circle { x::Float, y::Float, r::Float }

instance Show Circle where 
    show :: Circle -> String
    show circle = concat $ 
        intersperse "," (map show [x circle, y circle, r circle])
```